# Converting Time Zones from a String to UTC (JODA TIME)

Tags: java, android-studio, datetime, jodatime, datetime-conversion

I have a stored UTC timestamp in the database. When I retrieve that UTC timestamp I cast it into a String. I want to take that UTC Timestamp String and convert it to the device's local time using Joda Time. Anyone who could possibly help out with this. It would be very appreciated! Here is what I am doing right now:

```
                String date = ""+ds.child("datecreated").getValue();

                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

                DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(date);

                DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

                String personalDate = dt2.toString();

                dateTV.setText(personalDate);

                System.out.println("THIS IS THE FIRST TIME: " + dt + "THIS IS THE SECOND TIME: " + dt2);
```

The problem is is that it is giving me the exact same time when I convert it to my local time, which it shouldn't be doing since it is being stored in UTC and I am converting to Eastern Standard Time which is my phone's default.

Comment: So what is wrong with what you're doing right now? Please explain.

Comment: The problem is is that it is giving me the exact same time when I convert it to my local time, which it shouldn't be doing since it is being stored in UTC and I am converting to Eastern Standard Time which is my phone's default.

Comment: @Andreas I posted a response

Comment: Seems you need to **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`parseDateTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime-java.lang.String-): *the resulting `DateTime` will have the zone of this formatter, but the parsed zone may have caused the time to be adjusted*, which means that `dt` is already in the default time zone, so `dt2` is redundant. As the javadoc say: *If the `withOffsetParsed()` has been called, then the resulting `DateTime` will have a fixed offset based on the parsed time zone*, but you didn't do that.

Comment: *FYI:* `new DateTime(dt)` is redundant since `DateTime` objects are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that Andreas in the comment has hit the nail right on: I ran the following snippet in America/Coral_Harbour time zone (since I didn’t know your exact time zone, Eastern Standard Time is used in several (though fewer after 8 March when Eastern Daylight Time began)).

```
    String date = "2020-03-12T01:23:45.678+0000";

    System.out.println("This is the string:      " + date); 

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

    System.out.println("This is the first time:  " + dt); 
    System.out.println("This is the second time: " + dt2);
```

Output is:

> ```
> This is the string:      2020-03-12T01:23:45.678+0000
> This is the first time:  2020-03-11T20:23:45.678-05:00
> This is the second time: 2020-03-11T20:23:45.678-05:00
> ```

Compare the first two lines and notice that the conversion from UTC to EST has already happened when parsing the string.

As an aside, since your string is in ISO 8601 format, you don’t need to specify any formatter for parsing it. The `DateTime(Object)` constructor accepts it. But the same conversion happened in your parsing.

### What happened in your code?

Repeating the quote from Andreas’ comment:

> If the `withOffsetParsed()` has been called, then the resulting
>   DateTime will have a fixed offset based on the parsed time zone.
>   Otherwise the resulting DateTime will have the zone of this formatter,
>   but the parsed zone may have caused the time to be adjusted.

So your formatter has the default time zone of your device, and therefore also the `DateTime` object that you get from parsing.

So when creating `dt2` you were converting from Eastern Standard Time to Eastern Standard Time and therefore got the same date-time again.

**Link:** [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime()`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation. I understand clearly now!

Answer (score 1):

The part that you are missing is that, as the JavaDoc states, a DateTime object, internally, is represented by the number of "milliseconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z."

So, a DateTime does not have a time zone. Two DateTime objects that represent the same instant in time are exactly the same, regardless of the time zone represented in the string that you parsed it from.

A DateTime only "has" a timezone when you format it.
When you format it, you get a string with timezone that you requested, and the time representation adjusted accordingly.

The reason that the two dates (dt and d2) look the same to you is because you did not format them (you used their implicit "toString()" methods), so both got formatted with your local time zone.

Comment: A Joda-Time `DateTime` has a time zone (and a `getZone` method) (contrary to the poorly designed `java.util.Date`, which hasn’t).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but the main point of my answer is still correct, the two hold the same instant, and calling toString() without formatting arguments on both will yield the same string for both.